# Make GHC use libiconv.a (static lib) as opposed to libiconv.so (dynamic lib)

Tags: haskell, ghc, static-linking, dynamic-linking, libiconv

Is there any way to ask GHC to expect `libiconv` to be in a static as opposed to dynamic library? Currently GHC (7.10.2), expects that `libiconv.so` is in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Do you mean `ghc` itself or an executable produced my `ghc`? Probably related: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10912

Comment: I mean in something created by `ghc`, and more specifically, whenever I try to create a dynamic library containing all my Haskell code, it requires `libiconv.so` at runtime. I'd rather be able to include `libiconv.a` statically.